# How easy is it to find stores that do tax refunds in Tokyo?

Tags: japan, tokyo, tax-refunds

According to [this governament site](http://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/ttp/sg/09-TouristAttractions/MediumIndex/07-Shopping/E-Tax-fre.html), some stores offer tax refunds to tourists. Is it very common to find in Tokyo?

Specifically, I want to buy electronics at the [Ginza Apple Store](http://www.apple.com/jp/retail/ginza/). Will I be able to get a tax refund?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only larger stores that offer this, but you can always ask. I found a [German forum](http://www.macuser.de/forum/f33/apple-store-ginza-337649/) where someone claimed the Apple stores do offer tax free purchases.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use Chrome to translate from German, but it didn't go well :) Could you please enlighten me about what the user Tentacle said about Sakura-ya? Is there another store where I can get more points (what's that?), more discounts?

Comment: @Roberto: many electronics stores (like Yodobasi and Bic Camera) have a "points card" where you get a number of points for each purchase, which gets you a discount when you have enough points. In the forum there was disagreement on whether these stores give you such points for Apple products as well as the tax free purchase. As a tourist I don't think those cards are useful to you, unless you plan to buy a lot of electronics stuff. On the second page some advised to look for a cheaper offer (one one with some stuff bundled) in the stores in Akihabara.